# Is "まえのとおなじで" an adverb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Sometimes I get confused on the frontier whether an expression is an adverb or not.

For instance, in
政府はワインに新しく税を課した。(=the government has imposed a new tax on wine)

新しく is considered an adverb (made from the adjective 新しい) although there is no clear reference in a dictionary as the word lost its radical from type transformation. Some would claim it's an adverbial expression.

As of `まえのとおなじで` which can be literally translated as "same way as before" and can be used before a verb, would you argue that this expression falls into the specs of an adverbial type?

Answer (score 3):

The distinction between an adverbial expression and an adjectival expression is fairly strict and regular in Japanese. You can tell if a modifier is adverbial just by looking at its form. Here, 新しく is the [ku-form](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/i-adjective-ku-form/) (aka continuative form or 連用形) of 新しい, and it works as an adverb meaning "newly". The more literal translation of that sentence is "the government has newly imposed a tax on wine". Simply, 新しく, 赤く, 速く and so on modify verbs, while 新しい, 赤い, 速い and so on modify nouns.

で in まえのとおなじで can be either a case particle or the te-form of だ depending on how it's used in a sentence. If this で is a particle, then it works adverbially, i.e., it modifies a verb.